# how to check if ANY file exists in a certain folder with python?

Tags: python

How can I check if ANY file exists in a certain folder? I know how to check A file. which is as follows

```
a = os.path.exists("text.txt")
if a:
    print("file is there")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also duplacte of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

will list the files in the folder `folder`
script is running from `main`

```
folder
  files
  ...
  main.py
```

will list only files, not `.` and `..`

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
dir_path = os.path.join(dir, '../folder/')
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, f))]
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help

Answer (score 7):

use `os.listdir`

**Ex:**

```
import os

if os.listdir(path):
    print("file is there")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
folder = os.listdir("/home/yourname/yourdir")
if len(folder)>0:
    print "the folder is not empty"
```